# yarn install vs yarn upgrade (install not working)

Tags: node.js, reactjs, yarnpkg

I have a react app based on create-react-app. This is what I do:

- remove the node_modules directory
- `yarn install --pure-lockfile`
- `yarn build`

Then this results in these errors:

```
npm ERR! Linux 4.4.0-78-generic
npm ERR! argv "/usr/bin/nodejs" "/usr/bin/npm" "run" "build-js"
npm ERR! node v6.10.3
npm ERR! npm  v3.10.10
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! project@0.1.0 build-js: `react-scripts build`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
```

But when I do this:

- remove the node_modules directory
- `yarn upgrade`
- `yarn build`

Everything works fine. And note that there is nothing updated, the yarn.lock file stays the same.

Can anybody explain this difference?

Comment: Well the first obvious difference is that `yarn upgrade` recreates a lockfile and `yarn install --pure-lockfile` doesn't. Does running `yarn` then `yarn build` work?

Comment: Yeah I know, but I can see through git that there is no difference in the lockfile. No `yarn` and then `yarn build` doesn't work either.

Comment: How do you know the lockfile stays the same when `yarn install --pure-lockfile` doesn't generate one?

Comment: `yarn install --pure-lockfile` does take the lockfile and installs everything, correct?

Comment: copy `yarn.lock` then run `yarn install`. compare `yarn.lock` files. any changes?

Comment: Nope, stays exactly the same.

Answer (score 0):

Your current lockfile has a problem of some kind which `yarn upgrade` 'fixes' or one or more packages need upgrading. :)